# Need to create new database without using management studio

Tags: database, sql-server-express, sql-server-2008-express

How to create new database with SQL Server Express 2008 without using Management Studio?

Do i need to download sp1?

Comment: Using which programming language?

Answer (score 38):

You can use the [SqlCmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702.aspx) utility from the command line to execute SQL.

Open a command prompt and then type SqlCmd.exe and press enter, you should then get `1)` which means you are connected.

Once connected execute

```
1) CREATE DATABASE dbname
2) GO
```

Comment: While opening it the screen stays for 5 seconds then something is written on it and it closes instantly. How to fix this?

Comment: You can do it in a single line: `sqlcmd -U sa -P Passw0rd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -Q "CREATE DATABASE FOO"`

Comment: I will just add, that you don't need username and password, if our ODBC is setup to use windows authentication. E.g. when installed with Veeam.

Comment: @ChrisS i am getting an error while executing this command. On server there is no SQL Server Management Studio installed.

Answer (score 2):

Use [CREATE DATABASE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx) via [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702.aspx) or another other database connection (even VBA from Excel...)

Answer (score 0):

You could connect to it in code (.net express or something) with a connectionstring, then run an sql script to create a db (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx).

But why can't you use the management studio?

Comment: on executing managemnt studio i m getting message tht i need to download sp1..can i do without using management studio.